# Relative positioned element disappears when animating it's parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, browser

The elements `#open` and `#close` dissappear during the animation when they shouldn't be doing that.

Here is the code and under this box is the jsfiddle.

```
/* CSS */
#web { width:700px; height:600px; background:#ce5a3e}
#dreta { width:200px; height:600px; background:#000; float:right; position:relative }
#open { position:absolute; top:0; left:-50px; display:none; color:#fff; }
#close { position:absolute; top:0; left:-50px; color:#fff; }

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="web">  
    <div id="dreta">
        <a id="close" href="#">Close</a>
        <a id="open" href="#">Open</a>
    </div>
</div>
// JAVASCRIPT
$("#close").click(function() {   

    $("#dreta").animate({width: 0}, {duration: 1000,easing: "easeOutQuint",complete: function() {

        $("#close").fadeOut();
        $("#open").fadeIn();

    } });

});

$("#open").click(function() {

    $("#dreta").animate({width: '200px'}, {duration: 1000, easing: "easeOutQuint", complete: function() {

        $("#close").fadeIn();
        $("#open").fadeOut();

    }});

});
```

---

I have tested it in various browsers and they all make it disappear.

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aaQhF/1/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery sets a default style with `overflow:hidden`

You just need to add

```
$("#dreta").animate().css("overflow","visible");
```

To remove that default behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/aaQhF/3/